# Ошибка AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute

Tags: python, django

> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'OneDay'
>   Код в models:

```
class OneDay(models.Model):
    Author = models.ForeignKey('Profile')
    WhatYouWant = models.ForeignKey('Question')
    Date = models.DateField()
    WhatYouDo = models.TextField()
    Fillings = models.TextField()
    Events = models.TextField()
    Results = models.TextField()
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.WhatYouWant

class OneDayForm(ModelForm):
   class Meta:
       model = OneDay
       fields = ['WhatYouDo', 'Fillings', 'Events', 'Results']
```

В представлении:

```
from polls.models import Poll, Profile, OneDayForm
def oneday(request):
    template_name = 'polls/oneday.html'
    onday = OneDayForm()
    return render_to_response(template_name, {"OneDay": onday}, RequestContext(request))
```

В урл:

```
url(r'^one_day', views.OneDay, name='the_day'),
```

С формами вроде учусь работать. Смотрю-смотрю, вроде все правильно, но ошибка и все
. Что она означает хотя бы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Она означает, что в views.py нет класса модели `OneDay`. Да и в url модель передать не надо, надо передавать представление:

```
url(r'^one_day', views.oneday, name='the_day'),
```

Comment: Точно! Спасибо!

Comment: [Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)